# Is this possible install two version of php in one server

Tags: php

I this possible I install 2 version of php in on server and then set my website to use which one of them?
as example 
website1.com use php version 5.2 
website2.com use php version 5.4

Comment: yes, it is possible, we had a server with 2 version of php, but I dont remember how we are config them

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I dont try anything yet

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can install different versions as a CGI handler/fcgi, but you can install at most 1 as an apache module.

And you can use a php version manager to achieve this. Different version managers are available like:

```
https://github.com/c9s/phpbrew
https://github.com/CHH/phpenv
http://wilmoore.com/php-version/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not as apache module. You could set different versions using CGI, for example